# How to change the exposure of the photo in OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, exposure

Is there a technique that allows you to change the exposure of a photo?
I would like to know if there is a "generic" formula for having different degrees of exposure, for example:

```
1. Strongly underexposed
2. Underexposed
3. Correct exposure
4. Overexposed
5. Strongly overexposed
```

Code would be very welcome.

Comment: If you get photo from camera, could refer to [this](http://www.principiaprogramatica.com/2017/06/11/setting-manual-exposure-in-opencv/): `cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE,-4)`

Comment: Im using static photo (.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

As the page @JDevr mentioned, just read the Gamma correction part. I'm afraid you must manually adjust the gamma value, or just assume it. Sample code in python as followings:

```
def gamma_trans(img, gamma):
    gamma_table=[np.power(x/255.0,gamma)*255.0 for x in range(256)]
    gamma_table=np.round(np.array(gamma_table)).astype(np.uint8)
    return cv2.LUT(img,gamma_table)

image_gamma_correct=gamma_trans(image,value_of_gamma)
```